# VS 2005 Toolbox Messed Up

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I'm not sure when it happened, but at some point, my Visual Studio 2005 grew a group named "#13119" that I can't delete (it even shows in the toolbox when I have a code file open - it's the only thing in there.

Is there any way to fix this? I tried resetting the toolbox, and that didn't help. It's not a really big deal, but rather irksome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you've run into this issue:
http://zinovate.com/weblog/archive/2009/01/16/38234.aspx

From the blog post:

> 1. Make sure you can see all of the folders on your box. We are heading to the realm of hidden files: (Under Tools --> Folder Options)
> 2. Close Visual Studio if it is open.
> 3. Go Here: C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\
> 4. Backup the following files in a temp folder for saftey and delete the originals.
>
>    - toolboxIndex_reset.tbd
>    - toolboxIndex.tbd
>    - toolbox_reset.tbd
>    - toolbox.tbd
> 5. Restart Visual Studio and the files will be recreated. It'll take a few seconds for the toolbox to repopulate.

Comment: On my Windows XP box, the path was: C:\Documents and Settings\dfrankel\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0

But, regardless, that did it. Thanks!